# Finding months within a column of character values

Tags: r

I am working in R and have a dataframe with a column of dates that are stored as character variables in the format (YYYY-MM-DD). I want to subset my dataframe with only events that occurred in the month of February. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to `Date` class and subset based on the month format

```
subset(df1, format(as.Date(date), '%b') == 'Feb')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `lubridate` package, we convert your column to `Date` class and extract the month with `month()`:

```
library(lubridate)
your_data$date_column = as.Date(your_data$date_column)
subset(your_data, month(your_data$date_column) == 2)
```